# Handling new Window requests in a Cocoa WebView not opening proper link

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I am trying to handle new window requests in my web browser using the instructions under "Handling New Window Requests" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/MultipleWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002026-CJBEHAAG). When I click a link that opens a new window, I new window opens, but instead of opening the link I clicked in this window, it loads the url I have in my windowControllerDidLoadNib method. Why is this happening? Why is it not opening this link I clicked?